# XtraGrid FocusedRowChanged

Tags: c#, windows, devexpress, xtragrid

I really just don't get it . Taking off PictureBox1.Image will make label.txt works fine
but putting them together = not working . I even tried to remove label.txt & PictureBox still not working , 
CODE :

```
private void gridView2_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       string TheProducts = gridView2.GetFocusedRowCellValue("TheProducts").ToString();
       pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap("F:/Pictures/" + TheProducts.ToString() + ".jpg");
       label1.Text = TheProducts.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? You get any exception or error message? On which line? Are you sure your `TheProducts` isn't empty? Did you debug your code? And `ToString()` is redundant since it **is** already `string`.

Comment: Picture is not changing...
Label changes fine only if I remove PictureBox.image line

Comment: EDIT : Error Exeption : Illegal character in the way of access (on the picture box line)

Comment: TheProducts.ToString() might not be returning the right result? Put it all in a variable and use that instead of complex param. Also for strings you actually do not need .ToString()

Comment: Tried all that , still same thing ,please help :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your image locations' path seperator is wrong.

Try with `\` instead of `/` like;

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap("F:\\Pictures\\" + TheProducts + ".jpg");
```

Comment: Thought on that & tried it before & still same error.

Comment: What is the value of `TheProducts` exactly? Please debug and tell.

Comment: So, your one of your string will be `F:\Pictures\icon_product_0061.jpg` right? Are you sure this `jpg` exist in that location?

Comment: 100%
I tried alone  pictureEdit1.Image = new Bitmap("F:/Pictures/icon_product_0061.jpg");  & it works just fine.

Comment: @user3451838 Just to be sure, is `TheProducts` a string containing multiple values `"icon_product_0061 icon_product_0062 icon_product_0066"`, or each time it just contains one value, e.g. `"icon_product_006"`?